# Missing semicolon on Gitlab pipeline

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

In my localhost when I execute `npm run build` everything is ok, but in my Gitlab pipeline I have a syntax error.

The Gitlab pipeline was ok before I downgrade `react-scripts` from 5.*.* to 4.*.*

Now I have the following error:

```
Syntax error: Missing semicolon. (7:8)

   5 |
   6 | type BigInt = number;
>  7 | declare const BigInt: typeof Number;
```

I don't know very much about typescript.

Maybe I have a global configuration on my dev env who is now required by react-scripts 4.*.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the eslint configuration.

I don't know why it's different between my local and the Gitlab pipeline.

I added the file in my package.json to be ignored by eslint:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "eslintIgnore": ["src/components/Grid/index.tsx"]
}
```